# NodeJS parseFloat approximation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Why does the following happen in NodeJS.

NodeJS version 14.15.0.

```
> Number.parseFloat("37.12")
37.12
> Number.parseFloat("37.12")*100
3711.9999999999995
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
3712.00
```

Comment: I think my problem is Javascript specific if not would like to know

Comment: It's not JS specific. It's an issue with IEEE754 implementation as a whole. The duplicate has far more information.